# springboot 2.3.0 actuator liveness/readiness check returns wrong response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to test liveness/readiness locally using spring boot 2.3.0. When I expose API, it does return the right status, but not the right response. Based on https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot, I am expecting components, diskSpace and etc when I expose `/actuator/health`, but I am getting:

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "groups": [
        "liveness",
        "readiness"
    ]
}
```

I am pretty sure my pom.xml is right since it returns right status. I think it has something to do with configuration. Here is my local setup for configuration (application.properties):

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myurl.net;database
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

management.health.probes.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=readinessProbe,db
```

Am I missing something? Even if I call /actuator/health/liveness, all I am getting is

```
{
    "status": "UP"
}
```

"status" does show the right value (UP or DOWN), but components are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information exposed by the health endpoint depends on the `management.endpoint.health.show-details` and `management.endpoint.health.show-components` properties which can be configured with one of the following values `never`, `when-authorized`, `always`.The default value is `never`.

So if you set value of `management.endpoint.health.show-components` to `always` it should show what you are expecting.

For more details refer to the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health)